# Question about exercise 14.23 in TeXbook

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, paragraphs

In answer to exercise 14.23 it is said:

> The three paragraphs can be combined into a single paragraph, if you use
>   ‘\hfil\vadjust{\vskip\parskip}\break\indent’ instead of ‘\par’ after the first two.

But when I perform a check, it turns out that using `\hfil\vadjust{\vskip\parskip}\break\indent` instead of `\par` after the first two paragraphs does not produce the same as using `\par`.

Compare

```
\one
\par
\two
\par
\three
\bye
```

versus

```
\one
\hfil\vadjust{\vskip\parskip}\break\indent
\two
\hfil\vadjust{\vskip\parskip}\break\indent
\three
\bye
```

Why are the results different?

---

This is the header for both examples:

```
\def\one{Quid enim necesse est, tamquam meretricem in matronarum coetum, sic voluptatem in virtutum
concilium adducere? Nunc dicam de voluptate, nihil scilicet novi, ea tamen, quae te ipsum probaturum esse
confidam. Iam quae corporis sunt, ea nec auctoritatem cum animi partibus, comparandam et cognitionem
habent faciliorem. Si qua in iis corrigere voluit, deteriora fecit. Polemoni et iam ante Aristoteli ea prima
visa sunt, quae paulo ante dixi. Neque solum ea communia, verum etiam paria esse dixerunt. Non enim
quaero quid verum, sed quid cuique dicendum sit. Levatio igitur vitiorum magna fit in iis, qui habent ad
virtutem progressionis aliquantum. A primo, ut opinor, animantium ortu petitur origo summi boni. Nam si
quae sunt aliae, falsum est omnis animi voluptates esse e corporis societate. Quod est, ut dixi, habere ea,
quae secundum naturam sint, vel omnia vel plurima et maxima. Praetereo multos, in bis doctum hominem
et suavem, Hieronymum, quem iam cur Peripateticum appellem nescio.}

\def\two{Qua ex cognitione facilior facta est investigatio rerum occultissimarum. Conclusum est enim contra
Cyrenaicos satis acute, nihil ad Epicurum. Quid, cum volumus nomina eorum, qui quid gesserint, nota nobis
esse, parentes, patriam, multa praeterea minime necessaria? Quae cum ita sint, effectum est nihil esse malum,
quod turpe non sit. Cum ageremus, inquit, vitae beatum et eundem supremum diem, scribebamus haec. Sed
quid attinet de rebus tam apertis plura requirere? Sit hoc ultimum bonorum, quod nunc a me defenditur;
Minime vero probatur huic disciplinae, de qua loquor, aut iustitiam aut amicitiam propter utilitates adscisci
aut probari. Ut ei, qui iucunde vixerit annos decem, si aeque vita iucunda menstrua addatur, quia momentum
aliquod habeat ad iucundum accessio, bonum sit; Cupiditates non Epicuri divisione finiebat, sed sua satietate.
Nunc dicam de voluptate, nihil scilicet novi, ea tamen, quae te ipsum probaturum esse confidam. Quarum
ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur.}

\def\three{Alia quaedam dicent, credo, magna antiquorum esse peccata, quae ille veri investigandi cupidus nullo
modo ferre potuerit. Is hoc melior, quam Pyrrho, quod aliquod genus appetendi dedit, deterior quam ceteri,
quod penitus a natura recessit. Quid autem habent admirationis, cum prope accesseris? Cum praesertim
illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quos nisi redarguimus, omnis virtus, omne decus, omnis vera laus deserenda est.
Vide, ne magis, inquam, tuum fuerit, cum re idem tibi, quod mihi, videretur, non nova te rebus nomina
inponere. Quorum sine causa fieri nihil putandum est. Verum esto: verbum ipsum voluptatis non habet
dignitatem, nec nos fortasse intellegimus. Quae cum ita sint, effectum est nihil esse malum, quod turpe
non sit. Quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? Non quam nostram
quidem, inquit Pomponius iocans; Deinceps videndum est, quoniam satis apertum est sibi quemque natura
esse carum, quae sit hominis natura.}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX makes two passes when breaks a paragraph into lines. At the first pass it tries to split it without any hyphenation, and if it fails then at the second pass it adds the possibility of hyphenation.

In your case the second paragraph can be broke into lines at the first pass, but the combined three paragraphs cannot because of the first one. So, TeX makes another run, and this time it finds another splitting points just because the set of possibilities became larger (and also because it uses `\tolerance` instead of `\pretolerance` to limit the badness of the lines).